# Python 3.4 windows, pip install fails

Tags: python, windows, pip

I am struggling with adding to my Python 34 installation:

C:> pip install --upgrade pip
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip in c:\python34\lib
\site-packages
Collecting pip
  No distributions at all found for pip in c:\python34\lib\site-packages

What am I doing wrong?
Please help.

Comment: Give [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows?rq=1) a shot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run pip as a script and python will be the main executable.

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

The recommended procedure will be to update from get-pip.py

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Comment: that did not work either; I first tried:

    C:\>python -m pip install -U pip
    Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip in c:\python34\lib\site-packages
    Collecting pip
      No distributions at all found for pip in c:\python34\lib\site-packages

Comment: Then I put the curl output into temp.py and executed:///
python c:\temp\temp.py///
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600) - skipping///
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python34\lib\site-packages///
Collecting wheel/// and that had the same certificate error message

Comment: Let me try @WolfMetzner

Answer (score 0):

Seems I found the reason: the Windows computer is within a state agency behind a hefty firewall. I tried the same install with Python 3.4.3 from my laptop connected through my phone and had no problem at all. So, I think the firewall was in the way. Thanks for looking into this, @froost1999 and @Rockse .